# mongoid distinct with matching

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

In mongodb you could use command like

```
db.sessions.distinct("Ip",{ 'Application': '123'})
```

which will return all unique ip for the selected application. How to do that via Mongoid?

I trying to pass 2 argument in `distinct` function but it fails with exception `'ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)'`

Answer (score 1):

Distinct in Mongoid takes one argument -- the field you wish to filter distinct on. So in your case, you could chain a `where` clause w/a `distinct` like so:

```
 YourModel.where(Application: '123').distinct(:Ip)
```

This would produce a collection of distinct YourModel's by field Ip where the field Application is equal to '123'.

Answer (score -1):

Show you full distinct query, please.
I try follow syntax with users collection(3 documents with name Bob):

```
db.users.distinct("_id", {name: "Bob"})
```

And It's works:

```
[
        ObjectId("5121792d499af102889f2576"),
        ObjectId("5121792e499af102889f2577"),
        ObjectId("5121792f499af102889f2578")
]
```

My MongoDB version is 2.2.0

Comment: I know that it works in mongodb. Problems with Mongoid framework. Read question carefully.

Comment: Sorry) I think about MongoId, not framework.
Maybe this code can help: `Sessions.where(:Application => 123).distinct(:Ip)`

Comment: Yes, currently i implement it that way.

Comment: looks like there no other choice so edit your answer to allow me to accept it.